# Question about conditional probability and Baye's formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayes-theorem

I have the following sentence:

If I toss a biased coin with 2/3 chance of landing on heads, given that there was at least one head in 3 flips, what is the probability that there is only 1 head?

If we let $X$ represent the number of heads, then I can use $Baye's$ formula to find out the probability.

---

Which of the following would be the formula?

$$P(X=1 | X \geq 1)$$
$$P(X \geq 1 | X=1)$$

I think its the first one, but my sheet is saying the second one. I think it might have made a mistake. Which is the right probability?

Comment: Bayes' theorem addresses the problem of inverse probability. This is different from conditional probability.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mixing two concepts, but which would be the right one to choose?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem I don't think I'm wrong?

Comment: Nope, question still open

Comment: "Which of the following would be the formula?" Obviously, the first one. Additionally, note that the value of the second expression is always 1.

Comment: Yeah, okay my sheet made a mistake then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is some confusion, let me post some details.

There are $8$ possible outcomes for the three tosses.  As the probabilities for $T,H$ are not the same, these outcomes are not equally probable.

There are seven outcomes that have at least one $H$.  They are $$HHH,HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,TTH$$

The probability that we have at least one $H$ is $$P_{≥1}=1-P(TTT)=1-\left(\frac 13\right)^2=0.962962963$$

How do we compute the conditional probability?  Well, in this case we simply divide the unconditional probability by $P_{≥1}$.  Why?  Well, in general, conditional probability is defined by $$P(A\,|\,B)=\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$ Here $A$ is the event "you get exactly one $H$"  and $B$ is the event "you get at least one $H$".  Of course, in this case $$A\cap B=A\implies P(A\cap B)=P(A)=P(HTT)+P(THT)+P(TTH)$$  Thus our answer is the ratio $$\frac {P(HTT)+P(THT)+P(TTH)}{P_{≥1}}$$

Of course all three of those events, $HTT,THT,TTH$ have the same probability, namely $\left( \frac 13 \right)^2\times \frac 23$.  Thus our numerator is $3\times \left( \frac 13 \right)^2\times \frac 23=\frac 29=.222\cdots$

Finally the answer we seek is $$\frac {.2222\cdots}{0.962962963}=\boxed {0.230769231
}$$

Comment: I was following until you said at the end that the probability for $HTT$, $THT$ and $TTH$ is $(1/3)^3$. It's not a fair coin, and you had calculated it differently in the comments to my answer. Is it a slight of pen?

Comment: @AntoniParellada  There was a typo...which is now corrected (I believe).

Comment: Very nice! +1 Thank you for writing it up.

Comment: Which is $\frac{3}{13}$, as i got, thanks lulu!

Comment: `mat = replicate(10^6, sample(c(1,0),3,replace=T,prob=c(2/3,1/3))); at_least_one_H = mat[,colSums(mat)>0]; only_one_head = mat[,colSums(mat)==1]; ncol(only_one_head) / ncol(at_least_one_H) [1] 0.230344`

Comment: @AntoniParellada  Looks good!  Thanks.